# Changing mount directory lose disk's data?

Tags: linux

I have a problem about linux disk mounting.

I reboot my server lask week and know mount was released.
(maybe missing /etc/fstab configuration)

So I want to re-mount disk.

Question 1. How can I know where is released mount point?

Question 2. After re-mount(another mount point), disk's data is still alive?

please help.

Comment: Unmounting a disk does not do anything to the data on the disk (otherwise your data would all disappear every time you rebooted your system).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.